# how to use du to see files greater than a threshold size

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, disk-space-utilization

I am having a few situations to which I do not see any thing in du man pages.

1. I want to see files in a sub directory which are larger than a particular size only.
2. I use `du -sh > du_output.txt` I see the output as described for options `-s` and `-h`.
   However, what I am more interested in, is if the output comes in a format which
   is
   say for example

   dir0--->dir1-->dir3-->dir4
   |             |
   ->dir2        |-file1
   |-file2

If the above is directory layout and I want to just see the size of individual directories in all the subdirectories then what can I do (the depth of each subdirectory is variable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like the [gt5](http://gt5.sourceforge.net/) utility. It use the output of `du` and creates a browsable listing of directories and their sizes and uses a text-mode browser such as [links](http://links.twibright.com/) to display the information.

Both programs are available in the Ubuntu repositories: [gt5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/gt5) and [links](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/links).

[image: gt5 screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, gt5 looks very interesting it. I'm going to install it now. Of course there is also "baobab" for GUI.

Answer (score 55):

To only show folders over 1GB in size:

`du -h --threshold=1G`

You may also want to order by size, to easily find the biggest ones.
`du -h --threshold=1G | sort -h`

(Works on: Ubuntu/Mint.
Does not work on: OSX or RHEL 6.2)

Comment: Too bad `--threshold` does not work on OS X.

Comment: Also not working on RHEL 6.2

Comment: Also on Ubuntu it says `sort -hn` hn are incompatible.

Comment: @ScottStafford Thanks for that, typo, fixed.  Should have read just ``sort -h``

Comment: how to show files over 500KB? (instead of folders)

Comment: @AlexanderMills use `du -h --threshold=500K`

Answer (score 16):

Use the find command instead. The following example will show you all files that are larger than 10 megabytes:

```
find -size +10M
```

You can use du with find like this to see the size of each file:

```
find -size +10M -exec du -sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the answer by Mtl Dev fit for this question. Since Bond has opened this thread with tag 'linux' and 'ubuntu-10.04'.
Again, `du -h --threshold=1G` (followed by `| sort -h` optionally) works perfectly in Ubuntu.

Although, Bond said that,

> I do not see any thing in du man pages.

there're two lines in the man page, please refer below.

> -t, --threshold=SIZE
>   exclude entries smaller than SIZE if positive, or entries greater than SIZE if negative

One more thing, I think the exact command line Bond want is something like this,

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type d | xargs du -sh -t 1G
```

When `-mindepth 1` claims that it should contain the current path, `-mindepth 2` will work on your demand.

Below is a demonstration on the popular dataset [lisa](http://cvrr.ucsd.edu/LISA/lisa-traffic-sign-dataset.html).

```
~/dataset/lisa $ find . -mindepth 2 -type d | xargs du -sh -t 1G | sort -h
1.2G    ./aiua120306-0/frameAnnotations-DataLog02142012_002_external_camera.avi_annotations
1.7G    ./aiua120306-1/frameAnnotations-DataLog02142012_003_external_camera.avi_annotations
4.0G    ./negatives/negativePics
6.0G    ./experiments/training

~/dataset/lisa $ find . -mindepth 2 -type d | xargs du -sh -t 1G
4.0G    ./negatives/negativePics
1.2G    ./aiua120306-0/frameAnnotations-DataLog02142012_002_external_camera.avi_annotations
6.0G    ./experiments/training
1.7G    ./aiua120306-1/frameAnnotations-DataLog02142012_003_external_camera.avi_annotations

~/dataset/lisa $ find . -mindepth 2 -type d | xargs du -sh -t 3G
4.0G    ./negatives/negativePics
6.0G    ./experiments/training
```

Answer (score 0):

`find /path/to/folder -size +100k`

It's not clear if you are wanting to see the size of individual files which are larger than some value, or whether you want to see *folders* larger than some value.

Comment: both the things.Basically I have to make a report and in that I have to represent it in 2 ways both of which you pointed.

Comment: I think gt5 mentioned above may be what you are looking for.