# How to output all files/folders ordered by size, including hidden ones

Tags: linux, files, du, sort, directory-listing

How can I output all files/directories, ordered by size, including hidden ones 
(those whose name starts with a dot), all in one go?

By *size of a directory*, I mean the sum of all file sizes in the directory and all of its subdirectory tree.

The difference to [How can I sort the output of `du -h` by size?](https://serverfault.com/q/62411) is that I'm requesting an output that includes *all* files and directories in the current directory – *whether hidden or not*.

### References

- [How can I sort the output of `du -h` by size?](https://serverfault.com/q/62411)
- [How can I find the biggest directories in Unix / Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/q/200949)
- [How to use `du` to see files greater than a threshold size](https://serverfault.com/q/225777)
- [How do you sort `du` output by size?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4681)
- [How to list all files ordered by size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53737)
- [The `du` command does not parse hidden directories](https://superuser.com/q/342448)
- [How to get the summarized sizes of directories](https://superuser.com/q/162749)
- [Display each subdirectory size in a list format](https://superuser.com/q/554319)
- [A fast way to display the size of each subdirectory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307583)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> ***How can I output all files/directories, ordered by size, including hidden ones?***

Use the [`du` (disk usage)](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/du) command, which is part of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#File-space-usage) : <sup>1</sup>

```
du -hs -- * .[^.]* | sort -h
```

The `.[^.]*` [regular expression](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/NEWS/regexp.html#choose) ensures that hidden files and directories are included.

To list *only hidden* files and directories, sorted increasing in size :

```
du -hs -- .[^.]* | sort -h
```

List *only directories* – whether hidden or not – sorted increasing in size :

```
du -hs -- */ .[^.]*/ | sort -h
```

##### List only *files* in the current directory

List *all* files, sorted increasing in size : <sup>2</sup>

```
ls -AhlS | grep '^-' | tac
```

List only *hidden* files, sorted increasing in size :

```
ls -hldS .* | grep '^-' | tac
```

List only *regular* (non-hidden) files, sorted increasing in size :

```
ls -lS | grep '^-' | tac
```

##### List files *recursively* – in all of the subdirectory tree

This isn't asked about in the question, but sometimes you may want to list all files in the subdirectory tree (including the current directory), ordered by size. <sup>3</sup>

```
du -ah | sort -h
```

The output will be a list (possibly dauntingly long) of both subdirectories and files.
To restrict it to files only, you'll need to have an idea of what file extension the largest files have (by looking at the output from the above command).

```
du -ah | sort -h | grep .<file-extension>
```

Here you should replace `<file-extension>` with `zip`, `png`, `jpg`, or whatever file extension the largest files have.

Examples:

```
du -ah | sort -h | grep .zip
```

```
du -ah | sort -h | grep .png
```

### References

- [The `du` (disk usage) Linux man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/du)
- [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#File-space-usage)
- [In regular expressions, caret (`^`) means ***not***](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/NEWS/regexp.html#choose)
- [Comment on how to include both hidden and non-hidden files](https://superuser.com/q/342448#comment2474272_633808)
- [Utility Syntax | Guideline 10, *end of options*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)
- [The `ncdu` disk usage analyzer](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu)
- [Answer recommending `ncdu`](https://serverfault.com/a/201005)
- [The `ls` (list directory contents) Linux man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/ls)
- [How to reverse output in the command line](https://superuser.com/a/865551)
- [How to show only folders over 1 GB in size](https://serverfault.com/a/697119)
- [How to list all files ordered by size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53738)

---

<sup>1</sup>
I gratefully attribute my solution to [this comment](https://superuser.com/q/342448#comment2474272_633808).
The `--` argument [marks the end of options](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02). 
The `du` command can be painfully slow for very large files/folders.
Consider using the [`ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) command instead. 
To install on a Debian derivative, including Ubuntu, run: `sudo apt install -y ncdu`. 
On Arch Linux, including MSYS2, run: `yes | pacman -Syu ncdu`. 
To use it, type `ncdu`, and press <kbd>↵</kbd>.

<sup>2</sup>
The `-h` flag of [`ls`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/ls) outputs the file sizes in a human-readable style. 
The `-S` flag sorts the output in the order of *decreasing* size. 
The pipe  `| grep '^-'` excludes directories and symbolic links. 
The pipe  `| tac` [reverses the output](https://superuser.com/a/865551).

<sup>3</sup>
This is more likely to be of interest when the size of the current directory is a few megabytes rather than gigabytes.